# Resource Refactoring Tool for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I was searching for a way to **extract hardcoded string values to a resource file** to be able to easily edit the string values and maybe create translation files...

I found a Addin : the [Resource Refactoring Tool](http://resourcerefactor.codeplex.com/). But there is **two problems** :

1. It **only works for Visual Studio 2012 and lower** but I'm using the 2013 edition...
2. So I've searched for an updated version... and I [found one](http://seeseekey.net/blog/113744) (developped by a German) ! The new problem is that **I fail to install it**.

In the [linked zip file](http://seeseekey.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/ResourceRefactorTool2013.zip) on the previous website, there is a **"HowTo - Install.txt" file which contains** :

> HowTo - Install
>
> 1. Copy all DLLs to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Power Toys for Visual Studio\Resource Refactor Tool"`
> 2. **Copy `"ResourceRefactor.AddIn"` to `"C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins"`**
> 3. (Re)Start Visual Studio.

At the `2.` I've a problem because **I don't have the destination folder** (`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins`).

I've created the folder (useless or not ?) and **I've done all the instructions**, but it **doesn't work**.

I don't have `"C:\Users\Drarig29\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Addins"` also.

Then **I documented myself and I found [this](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/11/VS-2013-Extensions)**... I don't know what to do anymore.

Please help !

Regards, Drarig29.

Comment: What about https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ec5a225-dea4-47ae-8ebc-450d2980937f which is suggested by that same German guy?

Comment: Resharper (one of the most popular Visual Studio extensions) can do that, (extract string to resources), among dozens of other refactorings: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html

Comment: @sprinter252 Failed to install : `VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installed on any of the currently installed products.`

Comment: Is it giving you a list of applicable versions in output window. In doubt you should contact them.

Comment: @Nikolay Don't you know a free extension which can do that ? Because this one is not and I would not pay for that (I'm 16 years old)...

Comment: @sprinter252 I opened a "discussion" on your [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ec5a225-dea4-47ae-8ebc-450d2980937f/view/Discussions). I'm waiting for an answer. Thank for the help ;)

Comment: It's free for students/schools, check 'student' license: https://www.jetbrains.com/student/. As for the free alternative, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Nikolay It's not entirely free (I've to have a [ISIC card](https://www.isic.org/) and it costs 15€ in France) but thank you anyway !